# Python script not calling main function, says process finished with exit code 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Im using pycharm and it says Process finished with exit code 0 without my restaurant_list or anything after it

```
def main():
    # Make a list of resturaunts the resturaunteur could go to
    restaurants_list = ['Mcdonalds', 'BurgerKing', 'Wendys', 'PaneraBread']
    print(restaurants_list)
    # Remove expensive resturaunt from the list
    print('Here are the restaurants in the list')
    print(restaurants_list)
    # Get the restaurant to change
    restaurant = input('Which restaurant to remove?')
    # Remove the restauraunt
    restaurants_list.remove(restaurant)
    #Display the list
    print('Here is the revised list')
    print(restaurants_list)
    if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Do you ever **call** `main`?!

Comment: How would  call main?

Comment: Still didnt work when I called main()

Comment: Can you please paste your updated Python file, how you run the command and the actual given error message?

Comment: There wasnt a error message but still saying process finished with exit code 0 without the restaurants_list and afterwards

Comment: Your pasted code does not follow Python indentation rules. the last `if` must be on the same level with `main`.

Comment: Problem solved I got help from my teacher thanks for the assistance

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following at the end of the file:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

... to call your main function. Also make sure your PyCharm is configured to run the right script.

Comment: How would I configure it to run the right script the same thing happened,

Comment: @ImaniJackson the two lines posted by @Mikko must be indented at the same level than `def main()` (thus, no indentation is needed), **not** the same level than the `main()` function code.